# Difference of Positive Semidefinite Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have two matrices:
$$
A\succeq 0\\
B\succ 0
$$
and I know that
$$
\langle v_i,Bv_i\rangle - \lambda_i \geq 0
$$
for every normalized eigenpair $(v_i,\lambda_i)$ of $A$.  Is this enough to conclude
$$
B-A\succeq 0
$$
i.e., the difference is positive semi-definite? I can't seem to prove this or find a counterexample, but I suspect it is true.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong. Consider a simple example
$$
B=\Big(\matrix{1 & 0.9\\
0.9 & 1 }\Big)
$$
$$
A=\Big(\matrix{0.9 & 0\\
0 & 0.95 }\Big)
$$
Here $A$ and $B$ both are strictly positively definite and your condition is satisfied.
However $B-A$ is not positively semidefinite.

Answer (score 0):

As a counterexample, take $$B=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad A=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1} ;$$ then $B-A$ is not positive semi-definite.